# Python, TkInter, config() doesn't set text in a while loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have this function that sets my custom text label widget's text. Occasionally I want to display a number but in a way where like a number randomly increases until it reaches it. I've opted in for choosing a random number until I reach a small enough gap (10 %) when I just display the whole number. 
The thing is that `self.config(text=)` in the while loop doesn't set the text. The program just yields until the while loop is finished at which point it display the whole final value.

```
    def set_value(self, value, animated=False):
        if animated:
            goal = int(value.replace("+", "").replace("-", "").replace(separator, ""))
            temp = 0

            while temp < goal * 0.9:
                self.config(text=split("+" + str(temp)))
                sleep(0.1)
                temp += randint(temp, goal)

        self.config(text=value)
```

`split()` function just splits the number by a separator:
+1234567 --> +1 234 567

Edit: yes, I know this shouldn't work with negative functions, but I'm currently just testing the idea and will implement negative number support.

Comment: Are you sure that `self` is the `label` which you want to configure?

Comment: Yes, the class is defined as: `Class TextLabel(Label)`. Everthing else with self worked idk why it doesn't work in the while loop.

Comment: I doesnt see label defined, but I assume that you have no`textvariable = var` in your label, so you should refer not to the label itself, you should refer to `var`

Comment: I did that as well. And the same results. Everything outside the while loop set the text, or it set the Stringvar which set the label's text. But, everything inside the loop didn't. I even tried to recursively call the function with animation=False and that had the identical results.

Comment: are you sure that condition of the loop is true? If yes please make reproductible example otherwise people only have some guesses about the problem

Comment: During the execution of your `while` loop, those four lines are the *only thing your program is doing* - and none of them are anything that results in the GUI being updated, which is normally handled by the Tkinter mainloop.  The normal solution is to use Tkinter's `.after()` method to schedule the next step of your animation in the future, allowing the GUI to remain responsive in the meantime.

Comment: If you want the label updated in the while loop, add `self.update()` after `self.config(...)`.